# How to search an array of instance variables inside an array of objects in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, logic

Im trying to search an array of instance variables to see if it contains a variable which is inside an array of objects.

Now I can get the method to return a "true" boolean value when the array of instance variables contains the word I am searching for, but when the array of instance variables does not contain the word, nothing happens. The program never ends.

```
   //array of objects (lets assume it is filled with words)
   Dictionary[] dictionary 

   String output = "word was ";
   if (search(dictionary) {
        output += "found";
   }
   else {
        output += " not found";
   }           

   System.out.println(output);
```

Search Method

```
public static boolean search(Dictionary[] dictionary) {
  boolean found = false;
  String word = "Apples";
  int index = 0;

 //first create a loop tho go through all objects until found or no more objects
  while (index < dictionary.length && !found) {

     //check if Dictionary is a thesaurus or bilingual Dictionary
     if (dictionary[index] instanceof Bilingual) {

        //downcast that object
        Bilingual aDictionary = (Bilingual)dictionary[index];

       //get the array of instance variables for that a specific object at the index
        String[] words = aDictionary.getAllWords();

        int x = 0;

        //now go through the array & check if it contains the word
        while(x < words.length && !found) {
           if (words[x].equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
              found = true;
           }
           else {
              //go to next word 
              x++;
           }
        }
     }
     else {
        //go to next dictionary object
        index++;
     }
  }                 
  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index is only incremented in one case , you need to increment it either way so the search moves to the next dictionary object in case not found

```
     //first create a loop tho go through all objects until found or no more objects
while (index < dictionary.length && !found) {

 //check if Dictionary is a thesaurus or bilingual Dictionary
 if (dictionary[index] instanceof Bilingual) {

    //downcast that object
    Bilingual aDictionary = (Bilingual)dictionary[index];

   //get the array of instance variables for that a specific object at the index
    String[] words = aDictionary.getAllWords();

    int x = 0;

    //now go through the array & check if it contains the word
    while(x < words.length && !found) {
       if (words[x].equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
          found = true;
       }
       else {
          //go to next word 
          x++;
       }
    }
 }

    //go to next dictionary object
    index++;

}                 
return found;
```